# A* star algorithm help c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star

There is a problem with my open and closed list. If I alter B and move it around it does not work, but in some places in the map if I change where B is then it will work again. If anyone can assist me where I have gone wrong I would be much appreciative. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue> 

using namespace std;

class CNode
{
public:

    CNode() : xPos(0), yPos(0), travelCost(0) {}
    CNode(int x, int y) : xPos(x), yPos(y), travelCost(0) {}
    CNode(int x, int y, int cost) : xPos(x), yPos(y), travelCost(cost) {}

    inline CNode& operator=(const CNode& target)
    {
        if (*this != target)
        {
            xPos = target.xPos;
            yPos = target.yPos;
            travelCost = target.travelCost;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    inline bool operator==(const CNode& target) const
    {
        return xPos == target.xPos && yPos == target.yPos;
    }

    inline bool operator!=(const CNode& target) const
    {
        return !(*this == target);
    }

    inline bool operator<(const CNode& target) const
    {
        return target.travelCost < travelCost;
    }

    int xPos, yPos, travelCost;
};

class CPath
{
public:

    typedef vector<CNode> nodeList;

    nodeList Find(const CNode& startNode, const CNode& endNode, int mapArray[][20])
    {
        nodeList finalPath, openList, closedList;

        finalPath.push_back(startNode);
        openList.push_back(startNode);
        closedList.push_back(startNode);

        while (!openList.empty())
        {
            // Check each node in the open list
            for (size_t i = 0; i < openList.size(); ++i)
            {
                if (openList[i].xPos == endNode.xPos && openList[i].yPos == endNode.yPos)
                    return finalPath;

                priority_queue<CNode> nodeQueue;

                // Get surrounding nodes
                for (int x = -1; x <= 1; ++x)
                {
                    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y)
                    {
                        const int current_x = openList[i].xPos + x;
                        const int current_y = openList[i].yPos + y;

                        bool alreadyCheckedNode = false;
                        for (size_t i = 0; i < closedList.size(); ++i)
                        {
                            if (current_x == closedList[i].xPos && current_y == closedList[i].yPos)
                            {
                                alreadyCheckedNode = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (alreadyCheckedNode)
                            continue;

                        // Ignore current coordinate and don't go out of array scope
                        if (current_x < 0 || current_x > 20 || current_y < 0 ||current_y > 20 || (openList[i].xPos == current_x && openList[i].yPos == current_y))
                            continue;

                        // Ignore walls
                        if (mapArray[current_x][current_y] == '#')
                            continue;

                        const int xNodeDifference = abs(current_x - (openList[i].xPos));
                        const int yNodeDifference = abs(current_y - (openList[i].yPos));            

                        // Diagonal?
                        const int direction = xNodeDifference == 1 && yNodeDifference == 1; //? 14 : 10;

                        const int xDistance = abs(current_x - endNode.xPos);
                        const int yDistance = abs(current_y - endNode.yPos);
                        int heuristic = 10 * (xDistance + yDistance);

                        nodeQueue.push(CNode(current_x, current_y, heuristic));
                    }
                }

                if (!nodeQueue.empty())
                {
                    // Add the nearest node
                    openList.push_back(nodeQueue.top());
                    finalPath.push_back(nodeQueue.top());

                    // Put into closed list
                    while (!nodeQueue.empty())
                    {
                        closedList.push_back(nodeQueue.top());
                        nodeQueue.pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return finalPath;
    }
};

int mapArray[20][20] =
{
    { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
    { '#', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', 'B', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
    { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CNode start, end;

    for (int width = 0; width < 20; ++width)
    {
        for (int height = 0; height < 20; ++height)
        {
            if (mapArray[width][height] == 'A')
            {
                start.xPos = width;
                start.yPos = height;
            }
            else if (mapArray[width][height] == 'B')
            {
                end.xPos = width;
                end.yPos = height;
            }
        }
    }

    CPath pathFinder;
    CPath::nodeList n = pathFinder.Find(start, end, mapArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); ++i)
        if (mapArray[n[i].xPos][n[i].yPos] != 'A' && mapArray[n[i].xPos][n[i].yPos] != 'B')
            mapArray[n[i].xPos][n[i].yPos] = '*';

    for (int height = 0; height < 20; ++height)
    {
        for (int width = 0; width < 20; ++width)
        {
            if (width % 20 == 0)
                cout << endl;

            cout << (char)mapArray[height][width] << " ";
        }
    }

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Figure out exactly where your problem is, or at least a general area. Specify **clearly** what's going wrong. No-one wants to paw through your code trying to determine what you're talking about. Saying that something **does not work** only means anything to _you_.

Comment: What compiler compiled this for you without warnings?

Comment: I have said already that there is something wrong with the openlist and closed list. I dont know what is wrong hence why I have put the question up in the first place. I am using c++. The program works fine but if you edit the map code and change where the B location is and create a wall with '#' then the path does not come back down to B, but when you get rid of '#' and make a gap to get a new path its meant to find the shortest path but it doesnt...

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a number of things wrong with this:

1. You never pop from openList, which means that every time you check nodes that you've already looked at, and push nodes into openList that are already in openList or in closedList.  This adds a lot of computation.
2. You have a number of queues and lists when you really only need two.  You need one list (or even better, a map so that it's constant time to check whether a node has been already expanded) to keep track of which nodes have been expanded, and you need one priority queue to pull the next node from.  So instead of having a nested for loop for the openList, you'd just have the while loop, and then each time you'd pop off the node with the best heuristic value (i.e. the one you expect to get you closest to the goal based on your heuristic).

There are a few more details to work out with the final path, but I think having just two data structures instead of three will push your code in the right direction.

Comment: Okay thanks, do you have any way I can implement this as I am unsure on how to start or where to start. thanks

Comment: Well you've already used a priorityQueue in your code.  If you're confused about to use maps, there's always the documentation (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).  If you are wondering about the actual implementation, you have the skeleton set up, you just need to modify it a little so that you check one node for each while, get its neighbors, and push them into the PriorityQueue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time!  But the wikipedia article has good guidelines.  Good luck!

Comment: okay thanks for the help, one last thing could you point me to the bit in my code where you mean, sorry my english isnt very good and i find it hard to understand thanks

Comment: I am stuck in writing a cin line that takes the variables and then uses them for the locations to start in my a* algorithm..


int xA, yA, xB, yB;

    
   

 
  switch(rand()%8)
    {
        
  
  case 0: xA=0;yA=0;xB=n-1;yB=m-1; break;
        case 1: xA=0;yA=m-1;xB=n-1;yB=0; break;
       
    }

    cout<<"Map Size (X,Y): "<<n<<","<<m<<endl;


    cout<<"Start: "<<xA<<","<<yA<<endl;
    cout<<"Finish: "<<xB<<","<<yB<<endl;
    // get the route
    clock_t start = clock();
    string route=pathFind(xA, yA, xB, yB);